# Import array of modules (MDBootstrap js modules) into Laravel Mix

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, mdbootstrap

I have a fresh `Laravel 5.8` installation and I would like to include the js modules from `MDBootstrap`.

In my **`bootstrap.js`** file I have:

```
require('./mdb/modules');
```

The **`./mdb/modules.js`** file has:

```
exports.modules = [
  './js/_intro-mdb-pro.js',
  './js/scrolling-navbar.js',
  './js/vendor/jquery.easing.js',
  './js/vendor/velocity.js',
  './js/vendor/chart.js',
  './js/vendor/wow.js',
  ... 30 more
];
```

The compilation works ok, but of course, it doesn't take any effect from these modules include.

I don't know how to include all of them at once as they are not looking like a regular module so I can import like **`'import * from 'my-module'`**

I also tried the ES6 way:

```
import * as MDBootstrap from './mdb/modules';
```

but I got the same result: successful compilation without including them into the compiled js file.

The content of these 'modules' doesn't seem to look like a normal module where we **`export default {}`** or some other functions or variables. It looks like:

```
//mdb/js/scrolling-navbar.js
"use strict";

(function ($) {
   var SCROLLING_NAVBAR_OFFSET_TOP = 50;
   $(window).on('scroll', function () {
      var $navbar = $('.navbar');

      if ($navbar.length) {
         if ($navbar.offset().top > SCROLLING_NAVBAR_OFFSET_TOP) {
            $('.scrolling-navbar').addClass('top-nav-collapse');
         } else {
            $('.scrolling-navbar').removeClass('top-nav-collapse');
         }
      }
   });
})(jQuery);
```

Even **`'exports.modules = [..]'`** is not familiar to me. I know about **`'module.export = ...'`** but this **`'exports'`** looks like it's a Node.js object.

I know there's also another method to include the dist version of the plugin. I also tried it, but I got some errors: **`'Identifier '_classCallCheck' has already been declared'`**. I looked deeper and I found that actually many of those files are declaring the **`'_classCallCheck'`** function and of course that it a redeclare error. Maybe I can refer to this particular error directly to them (**MDBootstrap**).

So here I am, trying to include and use these modules/files in my Laravel project without success. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I found a solution by iterating over the module paths from the array:

Comment: Nice you have found it, **now share it!**

Comment: const mdb = require('./modules');

    for (var mdbModule of mdb.modules) {
 require('./mdb/' + mdbModule.replace('./js/', ''));
    }